# Python: webbrower and missing `GLIBCXX_3.4.29'

Tags: python, linux, python-webbrowser

I came across an import problem causing a runtime warning at debug time.
As soon as my python script invokes the open method of the webbrowser package, VSCode prints the following:
`/snap/core20/current/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1) Failed to load module: /home/andrea/snap/code/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so`.

There is nothing special in the code as you can see from the below two lines.

```
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open(url)
```

This is not a VSCode specific problem as the same script launched in the terminal output the same error.

Checking for the required GLIBCXX version at a system level, the required module seems to be in place (`strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`) as the required version is listed.
I have however upgraded the library to the most recent package without success.

At this stage, I'm not sure whether this depends from:

- the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, currently missing in my environment shell. I was somehow expecting PyEnv to do this for me? But this doesn't seem to be the case (I don't see any variable set by querying the os.environ.
- the fact the upgrade I did was not included in my Python built, hence I need to rebuild the package getting PyEnv doing the leg work for me

What would be your take?

P.S. I was simply trying to open a webbrowser and click on a link to cut short an authentication process I need to do to interact with my script.

Comment: Seeing `/snap/` in the traceback gives me the heebie jeebies (in the sense that Snap-installed packages have had weird issues that are only Snap-related). Did you install VSCode from a snap? Or your browser?

Comment: It comes from Snap, but how would this be affect it? In theory the environment is shared, isn't it? Beside, the script run by terminal does trigger the same error

Comment: Well, as a next step for debugging, add an audit hook (`sys.addaudithook`) to your script that prints out the audit data so you can see the exact command line that the `webbrowser`-underlying `subprocess.Popen` opens; then you can try and reproduce this without a Python at all.

Comment: I've never done this sort of things. Anything I can read to start with?

Comment: Just start with `sys.addaudithook(print)`, run your minimal example and show us the log.

Comment: It's a bit nutritious log. Is there anyway to redirect the otput to a log file I can copy paste into an online bin?

Comment: Of course, the regular shell redirection: `python something.py > foo.txt`.

Comment: Ah well yeah. I was looking at that via vscode at first

Comment: Dunno what's happening, by now it's no longer complaining.